# Can you comb the hair on a 4-dimensional coconut?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, spheres

It is well-known that you can't equip the surface of the unit sphere with a singularity-free coordinate system.  Physicists have called this theorem (which is important for the theory of black holes) "you can't comb the hair on a coconut."

What about one dimensional higher? That is, embed a $3$-surface of constant radius in Euclidean $4$-space (a $3$-sphere).  Has it been proven that we cannot equip that surface with a singularity-free coordinate system?  Is this question related to the Poincare conjecture (well, now the Poincare theorem since it has been proven)?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem under "Higher dimensions".

Comment: Well the 3-sphere is parallelizable as it's a Lie group, so yes.

Comment: Spoiler from that Wikipedia article: the short answer is that it alternates, so that $S^3$ has a tangent field, $S^4$ doesn't, $S^5$ does, etc.

Comment: As the other comments here (and my deleted answer) indicate, there seems to be a basic confusion in the question: "Combing the hair on a coconut" refers to the existence of a global nonvanishing vector field, but this is distinct from the existence of a global coordinate chart.

Comment: It's true that the existence of such a chart implies the existence of such a vector field (any of the coordinate vector fields, for example), and so if there is no global nonvanishing vector field, then there is no such chart, but the converse is not true: No compact manifold (of dimension $> 0$) admits a global coordinate chart (for the simple reason that it would give a homeomorphism between a compact set and a noncompact one), but plenty of compact manifolds, e.g., all compact Lie groups, admit nonvanishing vector fields.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  And you can do it two essentially different ways.

Any 4-vector can be represented as a pair of 2-vectors, whose elements can each be represented as a complex number.  In that notation, it is easy to show that
$$
   ( e^{i\phi} \cos \theta, e^{i\psi} \sin \theta )
$$
constitutes a parameterization of the unit 3-sphere in $R^4$.

A non-vanishing tangent field to the sphere arises from this parameterization, in the form of partial derivatives with respect to the three parameters.  At every point of the sphere, those three partial derivatives form the coordinate system you ask for.

If this tangent field is deemed a "right-handed" system with respect to the surface (that is, with respect to the outward normal to the surface), its negative will be a "left-handed" system.  The two handednesses are analogous to the two directions to go around a circle in the plane.

As to your question about the Poincaré conjecture/theorem: this insight would form an item of background knowledge in understanding the proof of the theorem, but by itself, it doesn't get you far.